# Crystal report on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, crystal-reports

Has anyone tried installing Crystal reports XI on Windows 7? Would be very grateful if anyone has any experience on installation.

Answer (score 1):

I installed CRXI and CR2008 (XII/12) on a windows 7 box over the summer. No issues or problems installing or running have cropped up yet.